# why my ajax method dont reach my controller method?, and never show the results of select

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I am developing a forum mvc oop (no frameworks), but  I got problems (for listing all the threads in the forum) , I have an  ajax method (button submit onclick - HTML in the view), I hope you can help me,my ajax method never pass to my controller method (doesnt list anything in the for loop), even though I create an instance of my class in the model, I dont know why doesnt list my threads??

This is my button
input type="submit" value="Show threads" name="btn" id="txtthreads" onClick="showThreads()"/>

ajax method

```
function showThreads(){

    //var page="../Controller/ControllerShowThread.php";


    ajax3=new objetoajax();
    ajax3.open("POST", "../Controller/ControllerShowThread.php");

    ajax3.onreadystatechange=function(){ 
        if(ajax3.readyState<4){
            document.getElementById("divvertemas").innerHTML="Executing.....";
        }                                                                              
        if(ajax3.readyState==4){
            document.getElementById("divvertemas").innerHTML=ajax3.responseText;
        }      
    } 
    ajax3.send(null);
}
```

Controller

```
    

$object = new Thread();
$result = $object->showThreads();


foreach($result as $array){
    echo "result";

}
?>
```

Model

function showThreads(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM thread";
        return $this->objConexion->executeQuery();

    }

I hope you can help me

Comment: why do you have `/` after `ajax3.responseText;`?

Comment: it was a comment but I didnt delete the /

Comment: this is wrong btw `showThreads()()`, should be `showThreads()`

Comment: ok I already edit but thats not the cause

Comment: what's the response from `ControllerShowThread.php`? check in Firebug if you have it installed.

Comment: I dont know how to use firebug, can you explain how to check for that controller

Comment: if you install firebug (firefox add-on) there's a console tab that's lets you see requests that you make, so in your case when `showThreads()` is called you should see a request to `ControllerShowThread.php`, see if it's successful, returns a response, etc.

Comment: objetoajax is not defined is the message of firebug

Comment: that's the problem.. you're calling on a function that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

1. Does your DB table 'thread' have rows in them?
2. Is something else in the controller causing the AJAX request to fail? Execute the controller directly and see if it echos what you expect
3. Does a DIV with the **id** 'divvertemas' exist in your view layer?
4. Install [firebug](http://getfirebug.com) and look at the XHR request/output and any Javascript errors

Comment: 1. yes 2. no indeed I put an echo there and It show when I click the button, but in the controller never get there because I make a for loop and dont show anything, 3. no, 4 Ok, -- I dont know but something this makes weird things

Comment: while you're not clear about the problem, this is better posted as a comment to ask for clarifications and not as an answer.

Comment: @yoan: You need to have a div with the id 'divvertemas'.. otherwise the getElementById will obviously fail.